# Is module __file__ attribute absolute or relative?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble understanding `__file__`. From what I understand, `__file__` returns the absolute path from which the module was loaded.

I'm having problem producing this: I have a `abc.py` with one statement `print __file__`, running from `/d/projects/` `python abc.py` returns `abc.py`. running from `/d/` returns `projects/abc.py`. Any reasons why?

Comment: Here's what Guido has to say about this: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-February/097461.html

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9271464/1959808

Answer (score 105, accepted):

*`__file__` is guaranteed to be an absolute path in Python 3.9+.*

In Python 3.4 [(changelog)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes)

> Module `__file__` attributes (and related values) should now always contain absolute paths by default, with the sole exception of `__main__.__file__` when a script has been executed directly using a relative path.

In Python 3.9 [(changelog)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes):

> ... the `__file__` attribute of the `__main__` module became an absolute path

---

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> The pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The `__file__` attribute may be missing for certain types of modules, such as C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter. For extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library, it's the pathname of the shared library file.

From the [mailing list thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-February/097461.html) linked by @kindall in a comment to the question:

> I haven't tried to repro this particular example, but the reason is
> that we don't want to have to call getpwd() on every import nor do we
> want to have some kind of in-process variable to cache the current
> directory. (getpwd() is relatively slow and can sometimes fail
> outright, and trying to cache it has a certain risk of being wrong.)

> What we do instead, is code in site.py that walks over the elements of
> sys.path and turns them into absolute paths. However this code runs
> before '' is inserted in the front of sys.path, so that the initial
> value of sys.path is ''.

For the rest of this, consider `sys.path` not to include `''`.

So, if you are outside the part of `sys.path` that contains the module, you'll get an **absolute path**. If you are inside the part of `sys.path` that contains the module, you'll get a **relative path**.

If you load a module in the current directory, and the current directory **isn't** in `sys.path`, you'll get an absolute path.

If you load a module in the current directory, and the current directory **is** in `sys.path`, you'll get a relative path.

Comment: so does it means that if there is a path from '' to the module, a relative path would be used, if not an absolute path would be used since the remainder of sys.path are absolute..

Comment: If you load a module in the current directory, and the current directory __isn't__ in `sys.path`, you'll get an absolute path. If you load a module in the current directory, and the current directory __is__ in `sys.path`, you'll get a relative path.

Comment: Remember, for this purpose, `sys.path` doesn't include `''`.

Comment: got it, but @agf, if i use python /foo/abc.py from /home, I suppose the part of sys.path that contains the module is /home/foo and my current directory is /home/, why does print file gives me a relative path?

Answer (score 63):

`__file__` is absolute [since Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes), except when executing a script directly using a relative path:

> Module `__file__` attributes (and related values) should now always contain absolute paths by default, with the sole exception of `__main__.__file__` when a script has been executed directly using a relative path. (Contributed by Brett Cannon in [bpo-18416](https://bugs.python.org/issue18416).)

Not sure if it resolves symlinks though.

Example of passing a relative path:

```
$ python script.py
```

Comment: This is not true for Python 3.4.0 (`Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux`). And symlinks are not resolved in my trials.

Comment: @FrozenFlame, feel free to report to https://bugs.python.org/ if 3.4.1 doesn't fix it.

Comment: It is now always an absolute path since Python 3.9 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes

Answer (score 21):

Late simple example:

```
from os import path, getcwd, chdir

def print_my_path():
    print('cwd:     {}'.format(getcwd()))
    print('__file__:{}'.format(__file__))
    print('abspath: {}'.format(path.abspath(__file__)))

print_my_path()

chdir('..')

print_my_path()
```

Under Python-2.*, the second call incorrectly determines the `path.abspath(__file__)` based on the current directory:

```
cwd:     C:\codes\py
__file__:cwd_mayhem.py
abspath: C:\codes\py\cwd_mayhem.py
cwd:     C:\codes
__file__:cwd_mayhem.py
abspath: C:\codes\cwd_mayhem.py
```

As noted by @techtonik, in Python 3.4+, this will work fine since `__file__` returns an absolute path.

Comment: ... except for the `__main__` module, where `__file__` *may* be a relative path.

Comment: even in `__main__` it will be absolute in 3.9+ now, that was mentioned in [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes)

Answer (score 6):

With the help of the of Guido mail provided by @kindall, we can understand the standard import process as trying to find the module in each member of `sys.path`, and file as the result of this lookup (more details in [PyMOTW Modules and Imports](http://pymotw.com/2/sys/imports.html#import-path).). So if the module is located in an absolute path in `sys.path` the result is absolute, but if it is located in a relative path in `sys.path` the result is relative.

Now the `site.py` startup file takes care of delivering only absolute path in `sys.path`, except the initial `''`, so if you don't change it by other means than setting the PYTHONPATH (whose path are also made absolute, before prefixing `sys.path`), you will get always an absolute path, but when the module is accessed through the current directory.

Now if you trick sys.path in a funny way you can get anything.

As example if you have a sample module `foo.py` in `/tmp/` with the code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
print (__file__)
```

If you go in /tmp you get:

```
>>> import foo
['', '/tmp', '/usr/lib/python3.3', ...]
./foo.py
```

When in  in `/home/user`, if you add `/tmp` your `PYTHONPATH` you get:

```
>>> import foo
['', '/tmp', '/usr/lib/python3.3', ...]
/tmp/foo.py
```

Even if you add `../../tmp`, it will be normalized and the result is the same.

But if instead of using `PYTHONPATH` you use directly some funny path
you get a result as funny as the cause.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('../../tmp')
>>> import foo
['', '/usr/lib/python3.3', .... , '../../tmp']
../../tmp/foo.py
```

Guido explains in the above cited thread, why python do not try to transform all entries in absolute paths:

> we don't want to have to call getpwd() on every import ....
>   getpwd() is relatively slow and can sometimes fail outright,

So your path is used *as it is*.

Answer (score 6):

`__file__` can be relative or absolute depending on the python version used and whether the module is executed directly or not.

**TL;DR:**

- From python **3.5 to 3.8**, `__file__` is set to the relative path of the module w.r.t. the current working directory if the module is called directly. Otherwise it is set to the absolute path.
- **Since python 3.9**, `__file__` is set to the absolute path even if the corresponding module is executed directly.

This behavior is explained in [**What's new In Python 3.9**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes) (thanks to [@user0's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/is-module-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative/72806441?noredirect=1#comment135820791_72806441)):

> Python now gets the absolute path of the script filename specified on the command line (ex: `python3 script.py`): the `__file__` attribute of the [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) module became an absolute path, rather than a relative path. These paths now remain valid after the current directory is changed by [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir). As a side effect, the traceback also displays the absolute path for [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) module frames in this case.

**Toy example:**
For instance, having the following setup (inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do/63313758#63313758)):

```py
# x.py:
from pathlib import Path
import y
print(__file__)
print(Path(__file__))
print(Path(__file__).resolve())
```

```py
# y.py:
from pathlib import Path
print(__file__)
print(Path(__file__))
```

with `x.py` and `y.py` in the same directory. The different outputs after going to this directory and executing:

```py
python x.py
```

are:

**Python 3.5 - 3.8:**

```
D:\py_tests\y.py
D:\py_tests\y.py
x.py
x.py
D:\py_tests\x.py
```

**Python 3.9 - 3.11**

```
D:\py_tests\y.py
D:\py_tests\y.py
D:\py_tests\x.py
D:\py_tests\x.py
D:\py_tests\x.py
```

Comment: So starting from Python 3.9, `__file__` is always an absolute path and can never be a relative path?

Comment: @user0 Yes, as of today (3.11 is the latest Python version) , `__file__` is always an absolute path.

Comment: Is there anything in the official documentation for Python that says so? The closest thing I can find is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes).

Comment: @user0 Your link is a great reference. The consequence that it also explains is that, before Python 3.9, if you changed the working directory (the directory from which the `__main__` module is called --`D:\py_tests` in my example above) using `os.chdir()`, the `__file__` attribute of the `__main__` module would be invalid. This is because `__file__` stored a *constant* relative path, unaffected by changes produced by `os.chdir()`.  After Python 3.9, since `__file__` constains an absolute path, its value remains valid after changes produced by `os.chdir()`.

Comment: What does this add over marcz's answer from 2014?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I should probably add a reference to it. This answer adds the Python 3.9-3.11 part (the different behavior depending on the python version).