# os.getcwd() vs os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Tags: python, django

I am using the os module to have relative paths in my Django projects `settings.py` file. The variable SITE_ROOT is set to the current working directory of the `settings.py` file and then used to reference all of the `static/media` directories also located in that same directory.

Heres my issue:

```
print os.getcwd()
print os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

In settings.py, the above statements both have identical outputs. but my template will only load if I use `SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Django looks for the templates here:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
```

SITE_ROOT set to `os.getcwd()` seems to make Django look for the templates folder in the directory ABOVE the `settings.py` file

I can just as easily not use `os.getcwd()` and my site runs fine, but I am curious what may be going on here :)

Anyone know?

Comment: Current working directory and `__file__` are unrelated. The first can change, depending on where you run your program from and whether you use `os.chdir` within, the other depends only where the module is placed in the filesystem.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As mouad said, `os.getcwd()` won't give you exactly what you're expecting.

`os.getcwd()` does a bit more than returning the current working directory. It defaults to $PWD in your env. It's not where the script is located but where you were when you *executed* the script.

Being in `/home/user` and doing `python manage.py`, `os.getcwd()` will return `/home/user`
Being in `/home/` and doing `python user/manage.py`, `os.getcwd()` will return `/home`

But it's still won't be always true since it's possible to use `os.chdir()`. It is in other word like doing `cd`. It will also change the return value of `os.getcwd()`.

On the other hand. `__file__` is the path of the module file. So you have to use this to be certain to have a path relative to your module instead of the current working directory that may change.

As ShawnFumo said, `__file__` might not be always absolute. To get a better idea on how it works, you can check that answer: [Python `__file__` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/python-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative). Also, as of Python3.4 `__file__` should always be an absolute path.

Comment: AH ok, that makes perfect sense with where django is looking for the template. THanks

Comment: Keep in mind that what `__file__` returns isn't always an absolute path so you should use `os.path.abspath` on it to be sure.

Comment: @Loic Faure-Lacroix: Nice explanation..Thank u :-)

Answer (score 12):

The command `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` returns the directory in which the code file is stored, but `os.getcwd()` gives you your current working directory which is by default where the code was executed, the latter can be changed using the `os.chdir()` command.

Answer (score 4):

`os.getcwd()` will **not** give you the path where the `settings.py` is located rather it will give you the path from where the script (in your case `manage.py`) is executed.

Answer (score 1):

If the two statements you show truly have the same output, then either should work.  So either: 1) they are subtly different, for example, one has a trailing slash, the other doesn't,  or 2) you are testing in one environment and running in another.