# My Python code works on my Mac. On PC Win10, it runs but doesn't recognise my, data files. path seems OK tho

Tags: python

I'm beginner - only a few months at this stuff.  So... maybe something dumb.    This is a GUI program with multiple modules, and the GUI works on both platforms. pathLib seems to be transforming the path as I would expect, backslashes from forward and prefixing the Windows root,   C: etc,  Both cases use Python v.3.9. I'm  also using PyCharm on both. OS is Catalina (Mac) and  Win10.      The data files are cvs from Excel, UTF - 8.   The data is in a folder in same directory as my source modules.      Any ideas?

```
myfile = 'dbm.csv'

csvFileObj = Path.cwd() / 'data' / myfile

with csvFileObj as datafile:
    dbx = list(csv.reader(open(datafile)))
```

Comment: try with `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` instead of `Path.cwd()`

Comment: You said that _"The data is in a folder in same directory as my source modules."_  `Path.cwd()` doesn't give you that, see [Diference between os.getcwd() and os.path.dirname(\_\_file\_\_)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453576/diference-between-os-getcwd-and-os-path-dirname-file)

Comment: Thanks for getting me straight about Path. cwd().  The reference Link you gave was very infromative.    So anyway, I redid my code per your idea (I think):   Now I have:   source_path = (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    data_path = os.path.join(source_path, "data")
    full_path = os.path.join(data_path, myfile)
    dbx = list(csv.reader(open(full_path)))

Comment: @– Fravadona Continuing the above... as before, this code works fine on my Mac, no-go on my PC.  I'm wondering if it it perhaps is not a path prbrlblem, but rather something tricky about Windowns handling of the file type suffix, or ... something eles.    Sorry about  my ugly code.  I'm also new ro mini-markdown - tying to figure that out too.

Comment: OK, this is in fact working now (and apparently was when I wrote the above,  So thanks for your guidance on that.  It turns out that I have a different problem at the same point in my code:  my cosole has an erroe message about an unrecognized unicode character in position 18.  I don't know how to locate position 18 either, but I'll have to submit that a a separate qusretion.   Again thanks for your excellent advise on the right way to get the path.