# calling a function defined in different python script within working folder

Tags: python, function

I am trying to call a function defined in file `lidar_source_code.py` from my main script `py_lidar_depressions.py`. There are numerous sources which explain how to do this such as [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-file/), however When I attempt this the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lidar_source_code'` is returned. I must say that I am not surprised at this error as at no point did I point to where the file is located even though relevant tutorials do not seem to suggest the need to. The code to import the file and all of the defined functions was as simple as the following.

```
from lidar_source_code import *
```

Is there something I am missing here. Am I correct that one must first define the path of the function containing file before importing it?

Thanks

Comment: No, the path of the import is relative to your current working directory, so if both of those files are in the same directory and the current working directory is the directory where both of those files are, you wouldn't be getting this error, you can check your cwd using `print(os.get_cwd())` (`import os` first obvs)

Comment: ahah ok that makes sense. however now i have tried `import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\maxduso.stu\\Desktop\\FCOR_599\\project_work\\harrys_idea")` and the same error persists even thought when I `print(cwd) I get the correct path

Comment: is that the same directory as where both of the scripts are located, do you change it before importing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453576/diference-between-os-getcwd-and-os-path-dirname-file