# How can I make my program have a consistent initial current working directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, working-directory, file-location

When I run the following script in IDLE

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

I get output as

```
D:\testtool
```

but when I run from cmd prompt, I get

```
c:\Python33>python D:\testtool\current_dir.py
c:\Python33
```

How do I get same result which I got using IDLE ?

Comment: This question is founded on a wrong premise; `os.getcwd()` is, indeed, how you get the current working directory. The problem is that **how you run the script changes what the current working directory is**.

Comment: In other words: the direct answer to the question is "not by anything in the Python code, but by **using terminal commands to move to `D:\testtool`**, and then running `python current_dir.py`".

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It seems that IDLE changes its current working dir to location of the script that is executed, while when running the script using cmd doesn't do that and it leaves CWD as it is.

To change current working dir to the one containing your script you can use:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print(os.getcwd())
```

The `__file__` variable is available only if you execute script from file, and it contains path to the file. More on it here: [Python __file__ attribute absolute or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/python-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative)

Comment: I would recommend against changing the directory as you might get non-deterministic results if the user expected to run the script from a different directory.

Comment: I agree with @FrederickOllinger, there is no need to change directory.

```os.path.dirname(__file__)```

is sufficient.

Answer (score 22):

Using pathlib you can get the folder in which the current file is located. `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded.
Ref: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

```
import pathlib

current_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
current_file = pathlib.Path(__file__)
```

Doc ref: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: Can't the current file location and the current working directory be different?

Comment: Yes, can you change the current working directory, cwd, with os.chdir(path). Change the current working directory to path. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os-file-dir

Answer (score 11):

Python's default `pathlib` library provides the cwd like so:

```py
import pathlib

pathlib.Path.cwd()
```

Comment: Great, I'm looking for pathlib library