# IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory python

Tags: python

i hav confirmed that "apples.txt" do exist.what is wrong with my code?

```
   def Loadfile(fileName):
        myfile=open(fileName,'r')
        next(myfile)
        for line in myfile:
            linesplit=line.split()
            print line

    print Loadfile('apples.txt')
```

Answer (score 3):

The file probably isn't in your [working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359698/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-using-python-3). Either change your working directory to where `apples.txt` is located, or provide a full path to the file such as `'C:\\folder\\subfolder\\apples.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

```
arq = open('C:\\python2.6\\projetos\\test\\list.txt', 'r')
texto = arq.readlines()
for linha in texto:
    print(linha)
arq.close()
```