# No such file or directory when using console despite working fine in IDE/IDLE

Tags: python, file

My Python file has been working fine during testing in VSC and also works fine when using IDLE. Unfortunately when I run the file using Python it crashes instantly and gives me the error

> FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.

This is the line of code it gets stuck on if that matters.

> clickSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("click.wav")

Thank you for any and all help. I am using Python for Windows if it helps.

Comment: Different working directories presumably.

Comment: @Voo Could you clarify what you mean by that please?

All files are in the same folder as the script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359698/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-using-python-3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find that file. Try to fix the path to a relative one. Or place "click.wav" in the same directory as your python file you are running using Python.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. All relevant files are in the same folder/directory so I can't imagine that's the issue. Could you clarify what you mean by fixing the path to a relative one please?