# What does Python's __file__ actually do?

Tags: python

I've always assumed that the `__file__` variable always gave you the current file name, but that doesn't seem to be exactly what it does. Since I've been facing a bug if I assume this to be true.

Someone told me "that `__file__` refers to the last module searched"
And this seems to be more accurate, but I'd like to know what `__file__` is really supposed to do.

I couldn't find anything concrete mentioned in the Python docs.
A lot places seem to mention it, but aren't very clear about it.

[`http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html?highlight=__file__`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/module.html?highlight=__file__)

[`http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/module.html?highlight=__file__`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/module.html?highlight=__file__)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/python-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative

Comment: *Someone told me "that `__file__` refers to the last module searched"* That someone was wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ha, well I was just using it as an example of how unclear I was about `__file__`

Answer (score 4):

```
 __file__ is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The __file__ attribute is not present
 for C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter; for
 extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library, it is the
 pathname of the shared library file.
```

from here:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-February/097461.html