# python unipath: path to current file directory (ancestor) outputs nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to learn [python-unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath) and have been getting to grips with basic commands. However, I have been stumped by this issue. So, I would like to get the ancestor(2) of the current file. So, on the python interpretter, I do something like this:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from unipath import Path
>>> ORM_ROOT = Path("/home/foo/lump/foobar/turf/orm/unipath_try.py").ancestor(2)
>>> ORM_ROOT
Path('/home/foo/lump/foobar/turf')
```

..which is correct and exactly what I want. 
Now, I wrap this in a file like so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# unipath_try.py

from unipath import Path
ORM_ROOT = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)
print ORM_ROOT
```

when I run this using `python unipath_try.py` I get no output! No import errors either.
I am completely baffled why this is - probably something really stupid.
Would appreciate any help/direction on this :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` instead of `__file__`.

This is because `__file__` contains a relative path in your case.

`__file__` can contain a relative path or an absolute one in different situations:

> So, if you aren't inside the part of sys.path that contains the
>   module, you'll get an absolute path. If you are inside the part of
>   sys.path that contains the module, you'll get a relative path.
>
> If you load a module in the current directory, and the current
>   directory isn't in sys.path, you'll get an absolute path.
>
> If you load a module in the current directory, and the current
>   directory is in sys.path, you'll get a relative path.

(quote from [Python __file__ attribute absolute or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/python-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! Accepted your answer now :)

Comment: Just a follow up question: is it better to use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` as default for all cases instead of `__file__`?

Answer (score 4):

If you run the script in the directory in which the file exists, `__file__` is `filename.py`.

```
>>> Path('a.py')
Path(u'a.py')
>>> Path('a.py').ancestor(2)
Path(u'')
```

Pass absolute path using [`os.path.abspath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

```
import os

from unipath import Path

ORM_ROOT = Path(os.path.abspath(__file__)).ancestor(2)
print ORM_ROOT
```

**Alternative**

You can also use `absolute()` method.

```
Path('t.py').absolute().ancestor(2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - indeed you are correct. However going to accept alecxe's answer based on time :)

Comment: @JohnJ, That's okay. There's also alternative. :)