# Installing/loading github::KMeansRex Python library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a python noob, trying to run the example in [the KmeansRex library from github](https://github.com/michaelchughes/KMeansRex). I use a ubuntu machine. This is a library that doesn't have a `setup.py` file. Despite several attempts, I have not been able to run the short code example shown on the project's github page's README file.

To try to install this library, I do:

```
git clone https://github.com/michaelchughes/KMeansRex.git
```

Then I do (as per the instructions on the github page, just naming the `.so` file `libkmeansrex64.so` instead of `libkmeansrex.so` as I am on a 64bit machine):

```
g++ --shared -o libkmeansrex64.so KMeansRexCore.cpp -I/home/path/to/eigen/ -O3 -DNDEBUG

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdmUbg9.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccdmUbg9.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so I do:

```
g++ --shared -o libkmeansrex64.so KMeansRexCore.cpp -I/home/path/to/eigen/ -O3 -fpic -DNDEBUG
```

(and this compiles without errors). Then I do:

```
cd KMeansRex/
```

Then I do:

```
python
```

I follow the instructions on the github for the example:

```
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np;
```

(so far so good). But then, I do:

```
import KMeansRex
```

only to get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "KMeansRex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from KMeansRex import RunKMeans
  File "KMeansRex/KMeansRex.py", line 30, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so') )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libkmeansrex64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which is odd, because the compiler did produce `libkmeansrex64.so`:

```
/KMeansRex$ ls -n
total 84
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000  4096 Mai 22 13:24 demonumpyctypes
drwxrwxr-x 3 1000 1000  4096 Mai 22 14:00 KMeansRex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  7003 Mai 22 13:24 KMeansRexCore.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   635 Mai 22 13:24 KMeansRexCore.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  2214 Mai 22 13:24 KMeansRex.cpp
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000 1000 41792 Mai 22 13:24 libkmeansrex64.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  1541 Mai 22 13:24 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  7899 Mai 22 13:24 mersenneTwister2002.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  1396 Mai 22 13:24 README
```

## Edit:

Problem solved (thanks to user `kvorobiev`). So before the line

```
  lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so') )
```

I added

```
  print os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so')
```

and the prompt prints:

```
libkmeansrex64.so
```

so it is clear that I should replace

```
  lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so') )
```

By:

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'/path/to/libkmeansrex64.so') )
```

Doing this, it all works fine;)

Comment: @renemilk: soory I do not understand. Could you explain better how to change the `dlopen` call?

Comment: Just open `KMeansRex.py` file and insert `print os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so')` line just before `lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so') )` and add results to your question

Comment: @kvorobiev: that fixed the problem! Should I delete this question?

Comment: I mean I replaced `  lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'libkmeansrex64.so') )` by `  lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( os.path.join(parentdir,'/path/to/libkmeansrex64.so') )`

Comment: I added a full answer with explanation. If it is helpful you could mark it as right answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with paths in KMeansRex.py.

```
import os
...

curdir = os.path.split( __file__ )[0]
parentdir = os.path.split( curdir)[0]
...
```

In Python3 this code will work correctly, since `__file__` contains absolute path to file. But in Python2 if [you aren't inside the part of `sys.path` that contains the module, you'll get an absolute path. If you are inside the part of `sys.path` that contains the module, you'll get a relative path.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/python-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative)
You could use

```
import os
...

curdir = os.path.split( os.path.abspath(__file__) )[0]
parentdir = os.path.split( curdir)[0]
...
```

or just hardcode absolute path to your library

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( '/abs/path/to/lib/libkmeansrex64.so' )
```