# Trouble importing modules from the same folder

Tags: python, import, enthought, canopy

I am having trouble importing a module that I created. This module is in the same folder that the module from which I need to import it is. I am working on a module thats called `directo_etapas.py` and from there I need to import `solvers.py`, so I go:

```
import math
import solvers
```

I don't get any error while importing math module, but I do get an error with `import solvers`.

I get this error:

```
"C:\Users\...\Codigos\directo_etapas.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File   "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 776, in structured_traceback
    records = _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 230, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 267, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    if rname == '<ipython console>' or rname.endswith('<string>'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.


**Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.**
```

Note that I'm using Enthough Canopy.

Comment: This error does not happen when you comment out `import solvers`?

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to having a non ascii character (ñ, á, é...) in your `.py` file? Maybe? Take a look here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The pathname contained an "á" so I renamed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback which you see is probably due, as @BorrajaX indicates, to working with a pathname or filename containing non-ASCII characters. (The underlying problem with non-ASCII pathnames is that Python 2 doesn't support unicode consistently, as Python 3 does; successive versions of Canopy handle these better, but still imperfectly.) For now, the simplest solution is to use only ASCII pathnames and filenames.

But if I understand your description, this unicode problem, while real and needing fixing, may be secondary to a different original error. (Note "your original traceback can not be reconstructed" suggesting that the unicode error  occurred while trying to report the original error.)

---

Your original error may be as simple as not realizing that in order to import a module, its path must be on python's `sys.path`. This should always be true of the standard `math` module, so you can almost always import it any time. But (surprisingly to beginners) it is *not* in general true of the directory containing the script that you are running. I.e. just because you are running `directo_etapas.py` doesn't mean that other files (e.g. `solvers`) in the same directory can be imported.

For the record, the "professional-grade" solutions to this problem are either to create a "python package" (look it up) containing all your related modules, or to "install" your library modules (e.g. `solvers`) into your python distribution so that they will always be just as accessible as `math` is. But these are probably more work than you want to do right now.

If this is indeed the source of your original error, then there are two easy ways to make sure that your modules' directory is on `sys.path`.

a) The simplest, though less robust, is simply to be sure that you are running from that directory, because `sys.path` usually begins with an empty string, meaning the current directory.

**If you are running your scripts within the Canopy GUI, then you can do this with the “Change to Editor directory” or  “Keep Directory Synced to Editor” commands as described in the Canopy User Guide section ["Change directory"](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#change-directory).** Otherwise, if you are running your scripts from a Windows command prompt, just `cd` to that directory before running your script.

b) A somewhat more robust solution, for modules that you'll want to be using more broadly but don't yet want the work of installing, is to put their containing paths into the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. For more on that, see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-).

(You could also write code to ensure that the desired directory is on `sys.path`, by looking up the directory that your main script lives in (see [`__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116925/1988991)), and then either making that the current working directory, or inserting it into `sys.path`. However those solutions smell a bit hacky.)

Comment: It worked!. The problem was that the pathname of the folder was containing the name `Hidráulica` with á so that character was causing trouble.