# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified '\\xml\\'

Tags: python, xml, windows, batch-file

Script will pick the xml file from XML folder and parse it, it is running great when I run .py file directly. But, when I call the .py using .bat file I am getting below errors.

**XML.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
REM A batch script to execute a Python script
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6
py GET_XML.py
PAUSE
```

**Python snippet for getting file name under xml folder**

```
import os
pathx = (os.path.dirname(__file__)+str('\\xml\\'))
list1 = os.listdir(pathx)
#GET Folder
#print(pathx)
paths = (''.join(map(str,list1)))
#GET Files inside Folder
#print(paths)
#Insert in xml parse
tree = ET.parse(paths)
root = tree.getroot()
```

*Error*

[image]

**Directory Structure**

```
Python(folder)   
  +GET_XML.py
  +XML.bat
  +XML (folder)
      +1231.xml
```

Comment: what is the output of the commented line `print(pathx)`?

Comment: c:\username\files\python\xml\

Comment: I see no reason to add "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6" to `PATH`. You're not running the .LNK shortcuts in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more reliable to join paths using `os.path.join`, it will take care of escaping the characters and pick the path separator for your system.
Try to use the following line:

```
pathx = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'xml'))
```

Comment: In this case, `os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns an empty string, because `__file__` is relative to the working directory. In this case `os.path.join` will simply return "xml", which is also relative to the working directory. However, any script that uses `__file__` should *immediately* get the fully-qualified path when loading, e.g. `script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)`, in case the working directory gets changed later.

Comment: I found what you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116925/7919597, it depends it if the module is in `sys.path`, but I also found that starting from Python 3.4 it is always absolute: https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes

Comment: I was talking about a script, not an imported module. For modules, if `__file__` is set, it should be absolute in Python 3. For scripts it depends on the path passed on the command line.