# How can I get the name of the module where a Table instance was declared?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy table defined like so

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Table

my_table = Table(
    "my_table",
    metadata,
    Column("my_id", BigInteger(), primary_key=True),
    ...
)
```

I am trying to inspect this instance to get the module where it was created. I have tried using `sqlalchemy.inspect(my_table).__module__`, `my_table.__module__`, and `inspect.getmodule(my_table)` however, all three return `sqlalchemy.sql.schema` which is the module where `Table` is defined rather than where `my_table` is defined.

**How can I retrieve the name of the module where I have instantiated `my_table`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the functionality by subclassing `Table`. In SQLAlchemy, `Table` specifically overrides [`Table.__init__()`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/0a07fd99dbb8122f8b0786d693506c849db58d9e/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L468) to make it a no-op:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    """Constructor for :class:`~.schema.Table`.
    This method is a no-op.   See the top-level
    documentation for :class:`~.schema.Table`
    for constructor arguments.
    """
    # __init__ is overridden to prevent __new__ from
    # calling the superclass constructor.
```

The key being that it does not invoke `super().__init__()`, so that sqlalchemy can take command of instantiation and whatever you do, that needs to be maintained.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Table

class MyTable(Table):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._where_am_i = __file__

my_table = MyTable(
    "my_table",
    metadata,
    Column("my_id", BigInteger(), primary_key=True)
)
```

In this case, `MyTable.__init__()` is still blocking the superclass constructor, but it also adds an attribute to the instance which will be the name of the module that the class is instantiated within. I specifically chose an obscure attribute name (`_where_am_i`) that is unlikely to be overwritten by sqlalchemy and using `__file__` returns the path of the module (but you can make that anything you want).

I tested that inserts and selects still work:

```
import logging
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(my_table.insert(), [{"my_id": i} for i in range(1, 6)])
s = select([my_table])
result = conn.execute(s)
for row in result:
    print(row)
# (1,)
# (2,)
# (3,)
# (4,)
# (5,)
```

And instantiation location:

```
print(my_table._where_am_i)  # 53302898.py (that's the name of my module).
```

External module:

```
# external_module.py

from sqlalchemy_app import Base
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Table
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger

metadata = Base.metadata

class MyTable(Table):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._where_am_i = __file__

my_table = MyTable(
    "my_table",
    metadata,
    Column("my_id", BigInteger(), primary_key=True)
)
```

And:

```
# 53302898.py

from external_module import my_table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(my_table._where_am_i)  # prints C:\Users\peter_000\OneDrive\git\test\external_module.py
```

Note how it returned the relative file path in the first test and the absolute file path in the external module test. You can read about that here: [Python __file__ attribute absolute or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/python-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative) but you can make that `_where_am_i` attribute return whatever you need to suit your application.

**EDIT**
The above solution requires subclassing the `Table` class *inside* the module where instances are formed, otherwise it will peg the module where the Class is instantiated, not the instances. If you only want to subclass `Table` once in your project you'd need to pass the location to the constructor.

This works:

```
class MyTable(Table):

    def __init__(self, *args, _where_am_i=None, **kwargs):
        self._where_am_i = _where_am_i
```

...but you get a warning upon instantiation:

`SAWarning: Can't validate argument '_where_am_i'; can't locate any SQLAlchemy dialect named '_where'`.

To avoid that, you'd have to override sqlalchemy's alternate constructor, `Table._init()`, strip out the location parameter and then delegate back up the chain:

```
class MyTable(Table):

    def _init(self, *args, _where_am_i=None, **kwargs):
        self._where_am_i = _where_am_i
        super()._init(*args, **kwargs)
```

Import from external module:

```
# 53302898.py
from external_module import MyTable

my_table = MyTable(
    "my_table",
    metadata,
    Column("my_id", BigInteger(), primary_key=True),
    _where_am_i = __file__
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(my_table._where_am_i)  # 53302898.py
```

All above tests still pass.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't scale well. If I put `MyTable` into a separate file so that I can share it between several tables, it gets the location of that file rather than the file where the table was instantiated.

Comment: Then your only option is to pass it in at instantiation time. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  If you refer to [the Python documentation index](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-_.html), you see that there are three entries for `__module__`: one for [a class attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48), one for [a function attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-34), and one for [a method attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-36).  Only those types of objects have the module in which they were declared recorded.  `my_table` is none of these; it's just an instance of the `Table` class, so the only `__module__` you can find on it is `Table.__module__`.