# How to get source file which python class/function/variable is imported from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have imported two modules like this:

```
from module0 import hello_func
from directory.module1 import hello_var
```

Where in module0:

```
def hello_func(): return "hello from module0"
```

And module1:

```
hello_var = "hello from module1"
```

How can I know from which file is each object being imported?

I tried to check `locals()` function but nothing in there giving reference to the file...

Comment: Stop using `from ... import *`. If you write `from module0 import hello_func` and `from directory.module1 import hello_var`, this is a non-issue. Both modules should *document* what values exist in the module and can be imported like this.

Comment: @chepner Other than variable overriding is there any other issue using it?

Comment: I'd argue the lack of transparency about what just got added to the global namespace is the primary problem. The overriding is just a symptom, because you might define a name `foo` which wasn't obviously imported from `module0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you kind of answered your question yourself:

> Let's say I have imported two modules
>   (insert "from xxx import *" here)
>   How can I know from which file is each object being imported?

One of the reasons of NOT using wildcard imports is precisely to make it clear where names are imported from (the other one being to avoind one imported name to shadow a previously imported one - something that tends to break you code in the most unexpected - and sometimes quite hard to spot - ways).

Note that in your edited question:

```
from module0 import hello_func
from directory.module1 import hello_var
```

you already have a much better idea where a name comes from. Not the exact files path yet, but at least the name of the package/module.

And that's one of the main reasons why one should NOT use wildcard imports.

Now if you want to know the exact files path, you have two distinct cases.

Some objects keep trace of where they were created (mostly modules, classes, functions, etc - cf the list of types supported by `inspect.getfile()`), and then, well, you already know the answer (use `inspect.getfile()` xD).

But most types wont (because there's no reason for it). In this case, you have to know which module they were imported from and call `inspect.getfile()` on the module itself. In this case, if you used wildcard imports, you will have to manually inspect all the modules you imported from to find out which one defined this name. Enjoy. Specially if one of those modules did also use wildcard imports...

> one question please: where they does keep traces? and how these traces look like?

Modules keep it in their `__file__` attribute. Functions and classes keep a reference to their module's name in their `__module__` attribute, and from this you can use it to retrieve the module from the `sys.modules` dict (a cache of all modules already imported in the current process), which will gives you the file.

I never had a need to search this info for tracebacks, frames, code objects etc so you'll have to check it yourself I'm afraid ;-)

Comment: @MohamedMsd afwan !-)

Answer (score 0):

You can define in each module a constant with its path, something like this should work:

```
import os

FILE_PATH = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

When you import that module you can access its location like this:

```
import module

print(module.FILE_PATH)
```

Comment: When is `__file__` *not* already an absolute path? (I think it is, but I could be mistaken.)

Comment: it could be a relative path, and then you will get wrong paths, always try to use absolute paths.

Comment: That's my question: *when* is it a relative path? I'm under the impression that it will always be set to the absolute path of the module to begin with, assuming the module comes from a file at all.

Comment: consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/is-module-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative

Comment: Because it doesn't actually answer the question, perhaps ? (just guessing...)

Comment: The question asks about identifying which module a name was imported from, not which file a module was read from.

Comment: Actually what he asked was this: How can I know from which file is each object being imported? What uniquely identifies a file is its absolute path.

Comment: I'm with @Marcos on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using the inspect and os modules.

```
import module0
import os
import inspect

print(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(module0.hello_func)))
```

Comment: Raising Exception: " is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object"

Comment: To be pedantic: in Python everything is an object, so "this doesn't work on variables" is actually false - a function, class etc IS a "variable". The distinction is whether the inspected object does keep trace of where it was defined. This is the case for functions, classes, tracebacks, etc, but not for most other types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the absolute path of where the script is being run, this should work for sure:

```
import os
abs_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(abs_path)
```