# How to convert module name to a relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of tests that inherit from a base class, which looks like this:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        module_dir = os.path.dirname(self.__module__.replace('.', '/'))
        self.payload_dir = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, module_dir, 'payloads')
```

This works fine, but `self.__module__.replace('.', '/')` isn't very *pythonic*, and won't work on Windows.

Is there a better way to convert a module name into a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the `__file__` attribute here. This will return the path to *this* file, which seems to be your module (but that isn't quite clear).

Depending on where in the path this is called from you may or may not need the `BASE_DIR` adding. You get a relative path if your inside the part of your path that contains the module, or an absolute path if you're outside. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/is-module-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative#:%7E:text=__file__%20is%20the,of%20the%20shared%20library%20file) for more details.

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def set_up(self):
        module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.payload_dir = os.path.join(module_path, 'payloads')
```

If you are not in the current module I believe you can use the module’s `__file__`  attribute.

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def set_up(self):
        module_path = os.path.dirname(module_name.__file__)
        self.payload_dir = os.path.join(module_path, 'payloads')
```

Comment: That doesn't work in my case because the class is inherited.  So each child class will have a `__file__` that references the parent, instead of the file that they are in.

Comment: I’ve added a potential way to address this, I’m on mobile so can’t test it at the moment.