# __file__ returns a wrong relative path after changing the current working directory in Python 3.7

Tags: python, filepath

Under certain circumstances, the variable `__file__` is relative (see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116889/is-module-file-attribute-absolute-or-relative) for details). If the variable is relative and one changes the current working directory, `__file__` doesn't change accordingly. As a result, the relative path is invalid.

Please see this minimal example:

```
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = __file__
    filepath_real = os.path.realpath(filepath)
    print('pwd', os.getcwd())
    print('relative', filepath, os.path.exists(filepath))
    print('absolute', filepath_real, os.path.exists(filepath_real))

    os.chdir('..')
    print('... changing the working directory ...')

    filepath = __file__
    filepath_real = os.path.realpath(filepath)
    print('pwd', os.getcwd())
    print('relative', filepath, os.path.exists(filepath))
    print('absolute', filepath_real, os.path.exists(filepath_real))
```

Suppose this file is located at `/home/user/project/script.py`. If I execute `script.py`, this is the output:

```
$ cd /home/user/project/
$ python script.py
pwd /home/user/project
relative test.py True
absolute /home/user/project/test.py True
... changing the working directory ...
pwd /home/user
relative test.py False
absolute /home/user/test.py False
```

Is it possible to get a correct `__file__` path (one that exists according to `os.path.exists`) after changing the working directory in Python 3.7? I am aware that this issue does not exist in higher Python versions (such as 3.9), where `__file__` always returns an absolute path.

Comment: assign the __file__ path at the beginning of the python file, which ensure that you get the path before changing working dir

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your suggestion might be a solution in some cases. However, suppose that I need to get the current filename of a module, where I call `__file__` in a function of this module. I don't know when this function will be executed. It might happen after changing the working directory. So, I would need to save the output of `__file__` in a global variable of this module rather than calling it in the function. Is this really the best solution in this case?

Comment: python interpreter evaluate the file line by line in sequence, so when you import the file, all codes have been evaluated and you path vallue is assigned, and import is only done once by interpreter except you are doing some advanced and dymaic import, otherwise, this guarantee it is executed before any function all.

Comment: I will paste my comments as answer if no more question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the `__file__` path at the beginning of the python file, which ensure that you get the path when the file is imported before you calling the function.

python interpreter evaluate the file line by line in sequence, file will be evaulated only once by interpreter even you import the file multiple times , so first time the file is imported, all codes of the file have been evaluated and you path vallue is assigned.

you will only have issue when you change working dir, then force reload the file programmatically and reimport the file, then the value will be changed, otherwise it stays constant duing life time of your program.

**EDIT**

below example to show the after you import the module, the `__file__` does not change after you change the working dir

```
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = os.__file__
    filepath_real = os.path.realpath(filepath)
    print('pwd', os.getcwd())
    print('relative', filepath, os.path.exists(filepath))
    print('absolute', filepath_real, os.path.exists(filepath_real))

    os.chdir('..')
    print('... changing the working directory ...')

    filepath = os.__file__
    filepath_real = os.path.realpath(filepath)
    print('pwd', os.getcwd())
    print('relative', filepath, os.path.exists(filepath))
    print('absolute', filepath_real, os.path.exists(filepath_real))
```

**output**

```
pwd /home/gftea/repo/jackygao/eiffel-system/utils
relative /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py True
absolute /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py True
... changing the working directory ...
pwd /home/gftea/repo/jackygao/eiffel-system
relative /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py True
absolute /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py True
```

Comment: Use backslash or code formatting to show double underscores properly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For a simple script, your suggestion might be perfectly fine. However, suppose I need to get the file path inside a function of a module. To apply your solution, I need to assign the output of `__file__` to a global variable in that module and use this global variable in the function. Some consider [global variables evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339). So if there are any alternatives, I would still be open to another solution.

Comment: OK, but to clarify
it is not global variable, the variable is module scope not global scope. not the same  as when declare with `global` keyword.  You access the variable by `mymodule.something`. 
you can get the builtin module file path in this way also, like `os.__file__`, I edit the answer for an example.